# jQuery scrollTop in container on click only works once

Tags: jquery, onclick, jquery-animate, scrolltop, jquery-click-event

I'm trying to make a content slider of sorts with the simplest jQuery possible, without a plugin and without assigning ids to each div.

I have a fixed position `#container` that is 100% width and 45% height of the page and contains 5 divs called `.sect`. all 5 `.sect` are 100% width of the container and are also 45% height of the page, which means that 1 `.sect` would fill the visible portion of `#container`, when scrolled to.

a div `#down` outside `#container` should, on click, make the `#container` scroll to each of the .`sect`s. this is my jQuery for it. I set the value of scrollTop to the height of `.sect` so that #container will scroll the exact height of each sect every time it is clicked.

```
$('#down').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#container').animate({ scrollTop:$('.sect').height()  })
});
```

the first time `#down` is clicked, `#container` scrolls from the 1st `.sect` in view to the 2nd `.sect` with no problem, but after that, `#down` doesn't do anything anymore. [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vq23tku7/8/) - the html and css aren't notable, i think. I'm new to jQuery so please explain what i'm missing!

Comment: Look into this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28052027/6294054

Comment: @J.C.Fong thank you for directing me to this! i read over and understood the logic behind the jQuery for their example and I applied the jQuery to my layout, but it doesn't work the same. it probably has something to do with my div height but i don't know exactly why it's not working the same https://jsfiddle.net/vq23tku7/14/

Answer (score 2):

I think you are missing that the container should keep scrolling depending on how much of scroll it has done, your code only scrolls down to the height of 1 .sect it should be like:

ScrollTop: scrolled + height

```
scrollTop: $("#container").scrollTop() + $(".sect").height();
```

Comment: thank you so much for this! i didn't read the scrollTop doc closely enough but now that I did, this makes sense! scrollTop is the position of the scrollbar of the element.

Comment: Glad i helped, i guess.